# Denying access to server.js in Express

Tags: javascript, security, express

I'm currently building a app which will be used in a production environment and I'm using Node & Express for that.

My concern is about the static file serving that I'm doing, because the server runs in the same directory (`dist/`) with the command `node server.js`.

Obviously someone just could do `<url>/server.js` and Express will happily return the whole content of the file, which is not good for security, of course.

I've now implemented a basic check which *should* deny the access to this file, like so:

```
[...]

function denyServerJSAccess(req, res, next) {      
  if (req.originalUrl.indexOf('server.js') > -1) {
    console.log("Denied access")
    return res.sendStatus(403);
  } else {
    return next();
  }      
}
app.use(denyServerJSAccess);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));

[...]
```

But is this sufficient?

Can a targeted attacked maybe craft a character that bypasses `indexOf`, but let's Express serve the file? That won't be any good, if yes.

I've seen so many tricks in the past that people use to get around basic protections that I'm a little bit concerned, as this probably *is* a basic protection.

What should I do in order to protect such files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't put them in the same directory, use a directory named `public` or anything like that in the directory that server.js is in and server only from there. Chances are there are more files you don't want anyone to access in that directory with server.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here, first the line

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));`

would expose everything that's in the directory `server.js` is in (this is probably your root directory). So you would like to limit the path to

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/path/to/public/resources'));`

And secondly, put public resources only under `path/to/public/resources`.

Comment: I don't know how I haven't thought of that. That seems definitively cleaner & also easier. Thank you.